# Function execution hangs if connection to Internet is lost

Tags: arcgis-python-api

I am trying to update feature layer. I am updating the records in a loop.

The problem is in the case Internet connection lost. It get stuck in the `edit_features()` function. I have to ctrl+c to stop script execution.

Is there a way to jump  to `except:` and continue the flow?

Here is my code:

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from IPython.display import display
gis = GIS("portal url", 'username', 'password')

#search for the feature layer named Ports along west coast
search_result = gis.content.search('title:Ports along west coast')

#access the item's feature layers
ports_item = search_result[0]
ports_layers = ports_item.layers

#query all the features and display it on a map
ports_fset = ports_layers[0].query() #an empty query string will return all 
ports_flayer = ports_layers[0]
ports_features = ports_fset.features

# select San Francisco feature
sfo_feature = [f for f in ports_features if f.attributes['port_name']=='SAN FRANCISCO'][0]
sfo_feature.attributes
try:
    update_result = ports_flayer.edit_features(updates=[sfo_edit])
except:
    pass
```